# TortoiseSVN, how to dump a repository?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I use Windows 7 and also I use TortoiseSVN to keep track of my code, now I want to migrate my repository to a cloud-service and the requirement is create a *.dump file, but I can't find a way to create it. Some forums say to use "svnadmin" but I can't find it also.

My question is how can I create a *.dump file with TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 13):

TortoiseSVN ships the `svnadmin` utility with it. It is a command line utillity. So you will have to create a dump of your repository in the command line.

To create a dump of your repository, use

```
svnadmin dump C:\SVN\MyProject > C:\tmp\MyProject.dump
```

where `C:\SVN\MyProject` is the path to your SVN repo and `C:\tmp\MyProject.dump` is the path to the dump file, which will be created.

To import your previously made dump file into a new repository, use

```
svnadmin load C:\SVN\MyProject < C:\tmp\MyProject.dump
```

where `C:\SVN\MyProject` is the path to your new SVN repo and `C:\tmp\MyProject.dump` is the path to the dump file, which should be imported.

Answer (score 12):

Subversion 1.7 now has the `svnrdump` command line utility.

`svnrdump dump https://host/repo > repo.dump`

Note that this always creates a dump with deltas, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I would like to add that during the installation of Tortoise SVN client, please do not forget to check the command line tool.

Comment: That's actually not the correct answer for the question asked. The question was most probably about a local repo, and for that you would use `svnadmin dump`.

Comment: In addition to creating a dump with deltas, it also requires https authentication.  I got "E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svnserver/svn/Common" and "E230001: Server SSL certificate validation failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted" - the svnadmin approach outlined by @Alexxus seems better, especially if converting repo to git and trying to take a backup to test

Answer (score 8):

TortoiseSVN is a svn client. It cannot take a dump of your repository. You need a tool like [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re31.html) on the server hosting your SVN repository to take a dump. You need access to the server and its filesystem.

Also see here for [migrating a repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5)

Comment: Like what @Anton Breusov said, the newer tortoise svn client also includes svnrdump.exe tool now.

Answer (score 1):

svnadmin is part of the SVN server, so you should have a direct admin access to your repository server.

Comment: is SVN server part of TortoiseSVN?. I am the only admin, what do you mean about "direct admin"?

Comment: TortoiseSVN (on your PC) is your client, whereas svnadmin should run on the SVN server (often a remote machine). However, TortoiseSVN can create a local repository (meaning that the server is running on your PC). If you use a local repository, check this link http://www.meinbinary.com/2009/09/migrating-local-repository-created-with.html

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is follow this tutorial to get some idea about how to use TortoiseSVN on the local machine.

http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/scm/svn/how-to-create-and-use-local-svn-subversion-repository-on-windows-or-linux-simple-and-fast-step-by-step

once you have done with above tutorial and committed your files to the repository, execute below command.

svnadmin dump TortoiseRepository > dumpfile

If your TortoiseSVN repository is not called 'TortoiseRepository' just change the name above to whatever you have called it. If the dump works you should see lots of '*Dumped revision' messages. The 'dumpfile' now contains an entire export of your TortoiseSVN repository and all the revisions, comments etc.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)