# How to start new svn repo from exisiting svn repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I pulled the SVN project to my machine and edited it.
From this modified version, I want to start new repository.
For example, I have this structure,

```
Parent
  |-Foo
```

I pulled `Foo` project, modified and named it as `Bar`.
Final structure,

```
Parent
  |-Foo
  |-Bar
```

How can I push this one without affecting the original project?
(I haven't push any changes to original project(`Foo`).)

Answer (score 0):

## Easy Way

If you want to commit the whole WC as monorepo and lost relation to original Foo-repo (The Bad Idea, if you want to maintain and sync changes some time longer, than "just now")

1. Create new fresh empty SVN-repo
2. Relocate WC to new URL
3. Commit

## Better Way

If you want to have modular structure and easy incorporate changes from upstream-repo later

1. Create new fresh empty SVN-repo
2. Relocate WC to new URL
3. Convert existing WC into "WC + pegged externals" (Foo dir, namely)
4. Commit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure of your exact needs (the existence of a "Parent" suggests you only want to create a branch within the repo but the description suggests you want to completely split "Bar" from "Foo"). Branching is trivial in TortoiseSVN (you even have a specific menu) so I'll only explain the second case. It's worth nothing that you need command-line utilities for many tasks. They're all bundled with TortoiseSVN but they're an optional component in the installation wizard.

- If you want to keep the original repository history, you need to grab a dump from the repository using the [`svnrdump` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480911/tortoisesvn-how-to-dump-a-repository), create a new repository and them import the dump with the [`svnadmin load` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html).
- If you don't care about history, just create the new repository and either import the raw files into the repo with the [`svn import` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) or simply copy them into a working copy and commit normally.